# Possibility of deleting very poorly thought-through question

Tags: support, deletion, moderators

A while ago, I asked [a very poorly thought-out question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923082/basic-proofs-introductioms-for-the-uninitiated). I was very far from erudite in what I was trying to express, and consequently, I would very much like to delete the question from the site, despite it having received a sensible response from @EmilioNovati , who, to his credit, tried to read between my rather fuzzy and obfuscated lines. Is there any way I could delete this question without causing upset or offence, or loss of reputation @EmilioNovati ? (I am perfectly happy to upvote one of his other great answers in compensation). I realise that what i am asking is non-standard, but I feel this question offers nothing to the community, nothing to me as a member of the community, and only serves to bring the quality of questions of this wonderful resource to unthought-out, sperculative nonsence. Is there any way I can achieve the above without being penalised?

Comment: The cheeky solution would've been to just downvote the answer and wait for autodelete to kick in.

Comment: Ha - didn't think of that - too late now though, I upvoted becasue he took the time to try to attempt to take seriously what perhaps should not have been !

Comment: In short, the answer is no. In extreme circumstances, it is possible to dissociate a post from an account, and you could use `contact us` at the bottom to request such a thing from the SE Community Team. But this does not seem like an appropriate action to me at this time. It seems better to me to leave it and move on.

Comment: @mixedmath ok - will learn from my rather rash mistakes!!

Comment: deleted now........

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you :)